# Customise the colors in JTCalender in iOS?

Tags: ios, jtcalendar

I am using JTCalender in iOS.I want to make color of labels such as date,month name in same color.As of now it is black for some dates.

[image]

Please suggesst how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize day views by using JTCalendar delegate methods

```
- (UIView<JTCalendarDay> *)calendarBuildDayView:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    JTCalendarDayView *view = [JTCalendarDayView new];
    view.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:13];
    view.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return view;
}
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    dayView.hidden = NO;

    // Test if the dayView is from another month than the page
    // Use only in month mode for indicate the day of the previous or next month
    if([dayView isFromAnotherMonth]){ 
        dayView.hidden = YES;
    }
    // Today
    else if([_calendarManager.dateHelper date:[NSDate date] isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Selected date
    else if(_dateSelected && [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_dateSelected isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Another day of the current month
    else{
        dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    // Your method to test if a date have an event for example
    if([self haveEventForDay:dayView.date]){
        dayView.dotView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        dayView.dotView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Note : The code is in Objective C, please use the respective methods in Swift.

Source : https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar

Edit: (As suggested by Kglay Kophyo)
You can change the color of month in delegate .

```
- (UIView *)calendarBuildMenuItemView:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar 
{ 
   UILabel *label = [UILabel new]; 
   label.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your color return label; 
}
```

Comment: how to change text color of month ?

Comment: Please suggest from where i can change the color of month

Comment: @deepakkumar - u can change the color of month in delegate .

- (UIView *)calendarBuildMenuItemView:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your color
    return label;
}